# Reverting a revert of a merge with old branch ahead of master

Tags: git, merge, git-revert

This is my situation.
On Branch X originally created from master (M) I did some commits. Then I opened a pull request and one colleague merged to master.

Then, this colleague noticed some problems and created a branch RB on which he did a revert of the merge to master.

In the meanwhile, I did another commit in branch X that has been pushed to origin. Now, If I open a pull request from X to master, I see a merge conflict related to my new commit, but all my changes made before the first merge are completely overridden by the merge revert.

```
X--X--X--X
       \
M-------M-----M
         \    /
         RB--RB
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your diagram (and desciption) indicate that branch `RB` which contains a revert _was_ merged back to `master`.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interactive rebase to selectively remove the merge commit in `master` which reverted all your changes.

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

This will prompt you with a list of commits looking something like this:

```
pick jd832ng some commit
pick bd381nv merge commit branch RB into master
pick al83mld an earlier commit here
pick f2ui2nd another earlier commit
```

Delete the line containing the merge commit, leaving you with the following:

```
pick jd832ng some commit
pick al83mld an earlier commit here
pick f2ui2nd another earlier commit
```

Now save this file, and complete the rebase.  You have removed the merge commit from the `master` branch.

**Note:**

If the merge commit from branch `RB` is the *most recent* commit in `master`, then you can nuke it using the following:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This will remove the head of the `master` branch.  If this happens to be the merge commit, then you are in luck and you can avoid the interactive rebase.  If, on the other hand, other people have made commits on top of the merge, then you are pretty much left with interactive rebase as an option.

Comment: But I want to get back the changes reverted. My colleague made a mistake.

Comment: @mat_boy You can use either `git reset` or `git rebase` in interactive mode to clean up the mess, q.v. my answer above.

Comment: I suspect that you may have botched the rebase.

Comment: I can tell you how I solved this issue. Maybe you can update the answer. Simply, I did the revert on master (from a fresh branch), solved again the merge conflicts due to the merge. Then, from the original branch X, I created a pull request to master, and everything was ok

Comment: OK...yes, revert is another option for undoing a commit, in addition to what I gave above.  I personally don't prefer it, because it creates a _new_ commit on top of your branch to undo something else.